# Tracking multiple sub-projects using Visual Studio 2012 git

Tags: visual-studio, git, version-control

I have been struggling with what (at least in my mind) should be simple:

I have two projects, the "MainProgram" and a "SubLibrary". Both were created with a Git Repository using the new Visual Studio 2012 Git support.

Both repositories work fine independently.

However when I "Add Existing Project"/SubLibrary to my MainProgram Solution, SubLibrary is not being "git-monitored" by Visual Studio at all  - no overlaid status icons in Solution Explorer etc. - its just as if that project was not under source-control.

Through some research, I added a git submodule to the MainProgram repo, added the cloned version of SubLibrary project to the solution and .. the git-icons in Solution Explorer appeared!!  ... but my joy was short-lived ..... No History, the status of changed files did not show in Solution Explorer. The changes were however picked up by TortoiseGit from within File Explorer.

The .gitmodules file looked OK (but as you can gather I am NO git guru!) .....

Surely it must be possible to have version control over multiple projects/repos within a single solution!

I would be very greatful if anyone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

In Git it is indeed usual to have smaller repositories. A typical repository will contain a single project while TFS and Subversion tend to have multiple projects in a single repository.

That will lead to the situation you described. Currently as far as I can see there is no git multi-repository support within Visual Studio (and TFS). It is simply not possible to have a single solution with multiple projects while each project resides in its own Git repository.

What I've done in the past:

- I created a directory that served as the root
- In that directory create a subdirectory for each individual project
- Clone each git repository in its respective subdirectory
- In a project use a file reference with a relative path to add references
- (optional) create a single MSBuild file that builds all the solutions in its correct order. This way you can create a build using multiple Git repositories.

You won't have a single solution this way, but you will be able to track your changes in each individual repository.

Hope this helps you.